# Smart Contract > 24kb

Tags: erc-20, voting, blockchain-size

I've a smart contract that's already optimised but the bytecode is still 60kb. (~1.5k lines, comments excluded (I know lines does not matter but it's to give you a better idea))

It's an ERC20Token that includes RFI and Voting, that's why it's so big.
I heard about proxies or diamond shape, but don't know if and how I can use it to reduce my smart contract.

Any idea on how I could make it smaller?

btw, I can deploy it on bsc-testnet, but can't use it in my tests inside brownie... weird stuff.
Would love to hear your piece of advise,
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This contract won't be deployable on mainnet.

You should look for a way to `encode multiple argument into one`.

Use `external Libraries for storage`.

And `refactor in multiple smaller contract`.

[Breaking one large contract to multiple smaller contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65187/breaking-one-large-contract-to-multiple-smaller-contracts)

There is no other way around your are stuck within these limits.

Comment: How can I use Libraries for storage? I already optimised the code to not have repetitive code and thus making libraries for them. Encoding multiple arguments are also already done and I can't make it more compact I think. Do you have any example of refactoring in multiple smaller contract? The token inherits from all of them in a way or another (Token is A, R - A is B - B is C - B is D)

Comment: There are plenty of article out there that will show you how to do this.